# URL and http get parameters

Tags: html, url

what is the correct way to parse a URL for the HTTP get arguments. For instance, google search

```
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1422&bih=700&q=blabla&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=
```

Wireshark shows

```
GET /search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1422&bih=700&q=blabla&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq
```

Parsing logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to parse the [Request-URI](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html).

Here's one way to do it on C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Returns the relative Request-URI from url. For example, given the url
// "http://www.google.com/search?q=xyz", it will return "/search?q=xyz".
//
// url need not be prefixed with a protocol; i.e. "google.com" is valid.
//
// If url contains a protocol (i.e. "http://"), the Request-URI begins with the
// first "/" after the protocol. Otherwise, the Request-URI begins with the
// first "/".
//
// If url does not contain a Request-URI, its Request-URI is "/", the server
// root.
std::string ParseRequestUri(const std::string& url) {
  const std::string protocol_identifier("://");

  std::size_t pos = url.find(protocol_identifier);

  if (pos != std::string::npos)
    pos = url.find_first_of("/", pos + protocol_identifier.length());
  else
    pos = url.find_first_of("/");

  if (pos != std::string::npos)
    return url.substr(pos);

  return "/";
}

int main() {
  const std::string test_url = "http://google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1422&bih=700&q=blabla&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=";
  const std::string test_url2 = "example.com/path/to/foo/bar/baz.tar.gz";

  std::cout << ParseRequestUri(test_url) << std::endl;
  std::cout << ParseRequestUri(test_url2) << std::endl;
}
```

The above code will output:

```
/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1422&bih=700&q=blabla&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=
/path/to/foo/bar/baz.tar.gz
```

Comment: this is most helpful, thank you. The original question is I have a URL with the query string. From it I need to create, the above mentioned GET string. URL has /search? and GET starts with /search?. So is the parsing rule look for the first single / and the rest + ? + query string is what the GET statement looks like? I know this sounds like a bizzare question, but what I am trying to do is not so easy, at least for me, to explain.

Comment: @reza: Thank you for the clarification. I have revised my answer accordingly. Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

the querystring is an array of key-value pairs. You could loop through them getting key and respective value. If you specify what programming language you use, i'll be able to provide code example

Comment: actually all I need to do is to reconstruct the get parameters from the URL.

Comment: sorry not too strong in c++. But the principle would be the same. Get the querystring, use parser to parse querystring string into Query Key-Value pairs using System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString (if you could add that reference) and iterate through the array